# Would Geddy have reacted differently in Advent if I hadn't dropped him off a cliff?

Tags: owlboy

During the attack on Advent, Otus rescues a prisoner with a broken leg. At first Geddy suggests that Otus should carry her to safety. However, in my playthrough Geddy quickly changed his mind...

> **Geddy**: Otus, maybe you can carry her to safety?
>
> **Anne**: Carry me? What if he drops me?
>
> **Alphonse**: Hahaha! Otus would never do such a thing! Isn't that right, Master Geddy?
>
> **Geddy**: ... *panicked* HAHAHA! NEVER! *runs away screaming*

...back in Vellie, I *might* have accidentally dropped Geddy off the cliff a few dozen times. I suspect this may have had something to do with his panicked reaction.

Would Geddy have reacted differently in Advent if I hadn't dropped him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Geddy's dialogue in Advent will change based on how many times you've injured him. Your save file has a *GeddyAbuse* counter that is incremented if you:

- Drop Geddy from a high distance.

  - (Amusingly, dropping Geddy off the cliff in Vellie does not count)
- Throw Geddy into a wall.
- Attack Geddy with a spin.
- Spin while holding Geddy, before getting the teleporter upgrade.

To test Geddy's reactions, I played through the game until Advent and made a backup of my save before rescuing Anne.

> GEDDY: Otus, maybe you can carry her to safety?
>
> ALPHONSE: Master Geddy, that's a great idea!
>
> PRISONER: Carry me? What if he drops me?
>
> ALPHONSE: Hahaha! Otus would never do such a thing!
>
> ALPHONSE: Isn't that right, Master Geddy?

#### Geddy was injured 0-10 times

> GEDDY: Of course!

#### Geddy was injured 11-20 times

> (*Pause*)
>
> GEDDY: Uh...
>
> GEDDY: Yes!

#### Geddy was injured 21-30 times

> (*Pause*)
>
> GEDDY: Um...
>
> (*Pause*)

#### Geddy was injured 31-50 times

> (*Pause*)
>
> GEDDY: (*Cowering*) ...I'm not sure this is a good idea.

#### Geddy was injured 51 times or more

> (*Pause*)
>
> GEDDY: Hahaha! Never!
>
> GEDDY: HAHAHAHAHA! O-Of COURSE not!
>
> GEDDY (*Running away*): AAAAAAAAAAAHHHH!!!
>
> (*Otis stares wide-eyed in disbelief*)